# Instantiate a List in DatabindingExpression

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

Is it possible to instantiate a list with view Id's in a databinding expression in xml itself?

E.g. consider this layout:

```
<ConstraintLayout>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/view1" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/view2" />

    <EditText app:hideWhenFocussed="@{listOf(view1, view2)}" />
</ConstraintLayout>
```

with this BindingAdapter:

```
object BindingAdapter{
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("hideWhenFocussed")
    fun hideWhenFocussed(editText: EditText, views: List<View>){
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
            when(hasFocus){
                true -> views.forEach { hideView(it) }
                else -> views.forEach { showView(it) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can declare the list as a variable, like so:

```
// This is possible, but feels like it can be done simpler
binding.views = listOf(binding.view1, binding.view2)

// In the xml
<data>
    <import type="java.util.List" />

    <variable
        name="views"
        type="List<View>" />
</data>

<EditText app:hideWhenFocussed="@{views}" />
```

but it would be so much nicer, if that can be achieved directly, without this overhead.

Here's some combinations I have already tried, but are not compiling (perhaps for good reasons ;) ):

`@{view1, view2}` using `vararg views:View` in the BindingAdapter

`@{listOf(view1, view2)}` using `views:List<View>`

`@{[view1, view2]}` using `views:Array<View>`